# How to change Visual Studio C# 2010 express License Key?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

I'm trying to make a tutorial how to register Visual Studio Express, but because I've already registered I can't register with a new account.

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall it, but the program is still registered. Is there a way to remove the license and re register?

I have found a way for Visual Studio 2012 but I think it's working for 2010 Express version.

Comment: You think its working?  Why don't you just use the new Visual Studio Community version?

Comment: it's working I just wanna make a video tutorial how to register and get the serial key for free !

Comment: Why?  It's self-explainatory how to do that...

Comment: well there is many thinks that it requires money to register so , please do you know how to remove the license ?